# Why is this D flip flop not working in LTspice?

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice

Below is the circuit:

[image]

I expect the Q1 Output should follow the clock since the DATA is set to one(5V), but the output is zero:

[image]

I looked for many examples but couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What does Q! output? What if you change to 5 V clock level (V4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HCT chip does not work with 1V clock. Use 5V clock.

Comment: Yes it works now. I will accept the answer but need to wait 6 minutes it says.